# Can you show that this equation can be derived from the relation $9\theta=-\sin 8\theta$, where $\theta = \frac{2\pi}{17}$ radians?

Tags: puzzle, polygons

It is known that the quantity $\cos \frac{2π}{17}$  is a root of the $8$'th degree equation,
$$x^8 + \frac{1}{2} x^7 - \frac{7}{4} x^6  -  \frac{3}{4} x^5  + \frac{15}{16} x^4  + \frac{5}{16} x^3 - \frac{5}{32} x^2 - \frac{x}{32}  + \frac{1}{256}   =  0$$
It is known that the regular $17$ sided polygon can be constructed from $cos \frac{2π}{17}$  , if this can be expressed in square roots.
Can you show that this equation can be derived from the relation $9\theta=-\sin 8\theta$, where $\theta = \frac{2π}{17}$?

Can you demonstrate that it is possible to solve this particular $8$'th degree equation, even though there is no $8$'th degree formula? ( there is more than one possible form of solution; it is known that there is often more than one expression in radicals for the same quantity)
Also, can you find a square root form for $\cos \frac{2\pi}{17}$  which has minimum number of terms?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE, please write your questions and answers using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), Also you have referred to many facts without any reference, please add the references.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos\frac{2\pi}{17}=\tfrac{-1+\sqrt{17}+\sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}}+2\sqrt{17+3\sqrt{17}-\sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}}-2\sqrt{34+2\sqrt{17}}}}{16}$$
See here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-cos%282pi%2F17%29%2B%28-1%2B%5Csqrt%7B17%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7B34-2%5Csqrt%7B17%7D%7D%2B2%5Csqrt%7B17%2B3%5Csqrt%7B17%7D-%5Csqrt%7B34-2%5Csqrt%7B17%7D%7D-2%5Csqrt%7B34%2B2%5Csqrt%7B17%7D%7D%7D%29%2F16

Answer (score 0):

It is known that the quantity Cos 2π/17  radians is a root of the 8th degree equation,
x8 + 1/2 x7 - 7/4 X6  -  3/4 X5  + 15/16 X4  + 5/16 X3 - 5/32 X2 - X/32  + 1/256   =  0
It is known that the regular 17 sided polygon can be constructed from Cos 2π/17  . If this can be expressed in square roots, can you show that this equation can be derived from the relation sin9θ=-sin 8θ. 
Where θ = 2π/17  radians?
Can you demonstrate that it is possible to solve this particular equation algebraically, even though there is no 8th degree formula? (there is more than one possible form of solution; it is known that there is often more than one expression in square roots for the same quantity)
Also, can you find a square root form for Cos 2π/17  which has a minimum number of terms?
(*A  reference for the 8th degree equation is: Wienstein, Eric, W, heptadecagon)